# How does Roadrunning work?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I know I get AP for every 1.25 miles driven, but does that reset every time I get out of the car or does it carry over between drives? For instance, if I drove 2.40 miles to my destination, then hopped back in the car and drove back to where I started, would I get 1 AP at 0.10 miles or at 1.25 miles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking whether the AP points are collected based on cumulative miles driven or if they have a base collection point given at X value for distance driven in Y session.

They're cumulative as far as *I've* tested.

1.) Chocobo experience gains are cumulative. I seriously doubt some developer was sitting there arguing the finer points of resetting driving AP gains despite cumulative Chocobo exp gain. If they did, some other developer probably dumped salt in the the coffee to make a point about how asinine that would be - or maybe I'm projecting what I would do - I dunno. Seems legit.

2.) Having a cumulative system reduces the compulsion to game it and encourages the player to focus on the important things, like making Ramen noodles for Gladios or requesting Prompto keep taking pictures of unimportant things at bad angles and horrible timing.

Comment: Yeah, you got the question correct. However, I got a bit hung up on the fact that the description of the Ascension skill was "awards AP for long drives" iirc

Comment: That's just a really convoluted way for the SqEnix to say "Lots of hours went into scenery. Manual  / Auto Driving is boring, but you can put it to use with this...then go hang out on the porch for 5 minutes and update facebook and smoke a cigarette on the porch until you get back to Hammerhead."

Comment: Can confirm that I have got AP/EXP awards within seconds of starting a drive so it is definitely cumulative.